# Old Domain Pay-per-click

Tags: domains, advertising

So you know when you go to a domain that say you want to buy, and the only thing that comes up is a bunch of links to other sites, and stuff like that?

How do I set something like that up for my old domain that I want to hold onto for the right buyer but, also make some small income while I have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google do something called adsense for domains: [Adsense domains](http://www.google.com/domainpark/)

You want to search on something like: Ads for parked domains and you should find more info and links to services you can use.

You may also find your domain provider has something you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is [Sedo](http://www.sedo.com/uk/park-domains/how-parking-works/) parking. Most of the big name Registrars use them when a domain goes past its renewal date. They will park it and see how much traffic it gets to determine if the domain is worth selling at auction.